# Currency Exchange Altorithm (Android / Java /Pseudocode)

Tags: java, android, algorithm, currency, pseudocode

I have a problem finding a good solution to the exchange currency problem. I've spent all the day thinking about this  with any elegant and fast solution for all cases.

Statement:

We have some exchange currency rates like...

- EUR to USD -> 1.37
- USD to AUD -> 0.7
- MEX to CAD -> 1.8
- LIB to YEN -> 2.3
- (.....)

This rates are not real and could change once a day. The number of rates could be as big as currencies are in the world (around 150).

We are asked to convert an amount of money from any currency to another one and we should give the answer (if we can) given the exchange currency rates.

The best case is if you exchange is direct (appears on the list), in the worse case you should jump a LOT of times in intermediate exchanges rates.

Note: Given EUR to USD you can assume uSD to EUR is the inverse.

I hope the problem is clear.

Any ideas??

Comment: Does the final rate depends on the particular route your algorithm takes?

Comment: No. It shouldn't. The rates are consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a weighted directed graph with each vertex labeled with a currency name. If you have a rate for currency A to B, add an edge (A,B) with the exchange rate as weight.

If you have an (A,B) edge but not a (B,A) edge add the (B,A) edge with weight 1 divided by the (A,B) weight.

To convert currency C to D, apply a shortest path algorithm to find the lowest weight path from C's vertex to D's vertex. If there is no such path, the conversion cannot be done. See [directed graph with non-negative weights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Directed_graphs_with_nonnegative_weights).

=======================================================================================

This won't necessarily find the best exchange rate, because the rates multiply. It could be made to find the best rate by using logarithms of exchange rates as edge weights, and using a shortest path algorithm that can handle negative edge weights.

To find the exchange path with the fewest exchanges, give each edge that matches a direct exchange a weight 1.

Comment: The rates are not real and could be any rate. Changing all the time. So you can´t use an intermediate currency.

Comment: Answering Patricia, my problem is what and how shortest path algorithm I should use. That's why I asked here.

I'd like to know too how people would build the grap.

Another question is.. Can Dikjstra Algorithm find the shortest path between any two points?? Could I use is here?

Comment: You can use Dikjstra's shortest path algorithm if the edge weights are non-negative. If you are minimizing number of exchanges, give each edge weight 1, and you can use Dikjstra. If you want to minimize exchange rate, using logarithmic rates, you will have negative edge costs and Dikjstra does not apply.

Comment: But Dijkstra algo is from a given source or for any pair of points?

According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem):

Dijkstra's algorithm solves the single-source shortest path problems.

A* search algorithm solves for single pair shortest path using heuristics to try to speed up the search.

I'm not looking for a single source, cause the source can be different on each call.

Comment: @Sotti Do you intend to pre-calculate the 150*150 possible conversions, or run the shortest path algorithm for the specific pair of currencies for each request?

Comment: The calculation is in execution time. You download a JSON with certain currency exchange rates (maybe 2, maybe 10, maybe 80, maybe 150...) When I get the JSON I make a graph with all transitions that JSON gave me. Then I am asked to make fastest as possible currency exchanges.

Is that more clear?

Comment: Roughly how many exchanges do you expect to do per exchange rate download? That drives whether it is better to run a single pair shortest path for each exchange, or pre-calculate the all-pairs shortest paths.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree largely with Patricia. But this problem surely surely has to do with avoiding arbitrage as well. So, it boils down to a 'shortest path' (lowest cost) from currency A to currency B. Shortest path algorithms are well studied and documented. Look them up in cormen and rivest.

Comment: This is it. Basically I should find the shortest path.

Comment: I would go with triangle arbitrage maybe in the future, but now I only want to know how to build the graph (I've made it but would like to hear other's opinions) and which shortest path algorithm to use and how!! Is the Dijsktra one valid here? I think A* is the one applying here.